# org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException: Undefined offset with no reset policy for partition

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are using Kafka Connect HDFS connector which is continuously pulling data from Kafka topics and committing them on HDFS.

After a successful 12 + 11 hour load, we suddenly found this error on connector side.

```
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException: Undefined offset with no reset policy for partition:Prd_IN_GeneralEvents-39
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffset(Fetcher.java:374)at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffsetsIfNeeded(Fetcher.java:227)at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1592)at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1035)at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:995)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:360)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:245)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And then a few (9 out of 100) HDFS worker threads got killed and we started getting data loss.

What is the root cause of this error?

We have set `auto.offset.reset=latest` in connect.distributed.properties file

Comment: First thing I noticed that the auto.offset.reset should have consumer as prefix (consumer.auto.offset.reset). Would you be able to provide the broker logs and just in case if you have the state stored for offset topic at the time of failure.

Comment: I tried with consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest in the morning. I see in the logs that auto.offset.reset = earliest is set. I dont know how is it pointing to earliest. Kept auto.offset.reset and consumer.auto.offset.reset both to latest in the connect.distributed.properties but still in the logs I see auto.offset.reset = earliest. There are a few more properties which are not overridden by values from my connect.distributed.properties file. consumer.auto.commit.interval.ms is set as 4000 in my connect.distributed.properties but I see auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000 in the logs.

Comment: I also see ----- [2017-06-21 16:10:01,321] WARN The configuration 'auto.offset.reset' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig:188) and [2017-06-21 16:10:01,366] WARN The configuration 'consumer.auto.offset.reset' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188) in my log file. Similar warning is present for many configs like consumer.enable.auto.commit, consumer.max.poll.interval.ms, internal.key.converter.schemas.enable, consumer.auto.offset.reset

Answer (score 1):

```
 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
 'properties.auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?